# nvm immediately regressing to an older version on terminal load, even though cli says I'm using LTS

Tags: node.js, shell, zsh, nvm

I have set a default node version using nvm. When I boot up a terminal (iTerm2) I see the following in the console:

```
Last login: Sun Apr 10 17:54:50 on ttys001
Now using node v16.14.0 (npm v8.3.1)
```

But if I type `node -v`, I see:

```
v12.17.0
```

Then, if I type `nvm alias` I see that I have the correct `default` aliases set up:

```
default -> lts/* (-> v16.14.0)
node -> stable (-> v16.14.0) (default)
stable -> 16.14 (-> v16.14.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/gallium (-> v16.14.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.10 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.19.0 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.14.0
```

I cannot figure out at all why my system always immediately regresses to version 12.

How can I ensure that my node version is always the default one I've assigned via nvm?